# No changes in object, updatedAt is being updated anyway

Tags: parse-platform

I'm writing JavaScript cloud code on parse.com and basically loop through and update the objects in my data from an external source.
I then use the updatedAt field to sync the updated records to an app.

I expected the updatedAt field to only change when I'd changed some data, even though I call save() like this:

```
query = new Parse.Query("Category");
return query.find().then(function(result){
    _.each(result, function(category){
        categoriesPromise = categoriesPromise.then(function(){
            // this is where I would do updates
            category.save();
        });
    });
});
```

For some reason this updates the updatedAt field, despite what it says on this page

https://www.parse.com/questions/will-calling-save-update-the-servers-updatedat-property-if-nothing-is-actually-changed-on-the-object

> No, if nothing has changed, executing .save() should have no effect.

Should I expect the updatedAt field to remain unchanged if I call save() without setting anything?  How about when I only overwrite fields with the same value that was already there?

Comment: **Update**  this doesn't seem to be happening any more, the updatedAt is no longer changing after running save()

Comment: **Update** the same code running today _is_ updating the timestamp.  Seems nondeterministic